# How to clear search parameters in angular

Tags: angularjs

I know that to clear a search parameter I can use

```
$location.search('');
$location.search('parameter', null);
```

But what I do not quite understand is when I should do it. 
I was thinking to do something like

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
   $location.search('');
});
```

So every time my path changes, I clear the search parameter from the url. But this does not seem a good solution. For example if I copy and paste an url with a search parameter in a new tab, this listener will be triggered and I will lose my parameter. And probably there are more cases where this implementation will cause me trouble.

My question is, what is the right way to deal with search parameters, and clear them whenever I go to another path, or keep them according to my needs.

Comment: have you tried ui-router with html5mode=true? That way you don't have to worry about managing the locations your self. Read https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag